# Minimizing database overhead by storing additional information to the users authentication-object (Spring Security)

Tags: java, database, spring

I am using Spring Security in order to check if a logged in user is authenticated. However, after authentication, as some actual requests come in, I would like to minimize the number of database calls as much as possible.

Hence my question: From the `SecurityContextHolder` I can get my hands on the `User` object using `getPrincipal()` of the `Authentication` object:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public List<StoreDTO> getAvailableStores() {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();       
    User user = (User)auth.getPrincipal();      
    String username = user.getUsername();

    List<Store> storeList = this.storeAdminRepository.getStores(username);

    return Convert.toStoreDtoList(restaurantList);
}
```

Would it be "*dirty*", instead of setting the simple `User` object as principal, to use a custom object that e.g. also stores the user id from *inside the database*?

The way I am doing it now would require me to look up the user id first according to his name and then get the stores `where user.id = store.user_id` or something like that.

Assume that there are a lot of requests coming and - is this a way to minimize the overhead? Or, and this could also be true, are my concerns unfounded since the overhead is by far not that large like I am assuming here?